# Can't connect to /home/ubuntu/env/Project/Project.sock

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, ubuntu-18.04

Am trying to host a we application using gunicorn and nginx. But I cant start the gunicorn service. everytime am getting the error message.
This is the error am getting

```
(env) root@ip-172-31-21-54:/home/env# sudo systemctl status gunicorn
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-12-17 14:59:42 UTC; 488ms ago
Process: 14160 ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - -- 
workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/env/Project/Project.sock 
Project.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 14160 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 17 14:59:36 ip-172-31-21-54 systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Dec 17 14:59:37 ip-172-31-21-54 gunicorn[14160]: [2018-12-17 14:59:37 +0000] 
[14160] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
Dec 17 14:59:37 ip-172-31-21-54 gunicorn[14160]: [2018-12-17 14:59:37 +0000]             
[14160] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 17 14:59:38 ip-172-31-21-54 gunicorn[14160]: [2018-12-17 14:59:38 +0000] 
[14160] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 17 14:59:39 ip-172-31-21-54 gunicorn[14160]: [2018-12-17 14:59:39 +0000] 
[14160] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 17 14:59:40 ip-172-31-21-54 gunicorn[14160]: [2018-12-17 14:59:40 +0000] 
[14160] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 17 14:59:41 ip-172-31-21-54 gunicorn[14160]: [2018-12-17 14:59:41 +0000]         [14160] [ERROR] Retrying in 1 second.
Dec 17 14:59:42 ip-172-31-21-54 gunicorn[14160]: [2018-12-17 14:59:42 +0000] [14160] [ERROR] Can't connect to /home/ubuntu/env/Project/Project.sock
Dec 17 14:59:42 ip-172-31-21-54 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process     exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 17 14:59:42 ip-172-31-21-54 systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And My gunicorn.service file is

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/env/Project
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - 
--workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/env/Project/Project.sock    
Project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I cant find the error.. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Does `/home/ubuntu/env/Project/Project.sock` at any point? Does `ubuntu:www-data` have access to write to `/home/ubuntu/env/Project`?

Comment: But it doesnt solved my problem. Now am getting the error like this' `gunicorn.service: Failed at step GROUP spawning /home/ubuntu/venv/bin/gunicorn: No such process`